# mapAs, filterAs, subscribeNextAs for ReactiveCocoa 3.0

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

Saw on Colin Eberhart's pdfs floating around that he made those extensions himself. He had written subscribeNextAs but not any of the others in Swift.

Is the below correct?

```
extension RACSignal {

    func subscribeNextAs<T>(nextClosure:(T) -> ()) -> () {
        self.subscribeNext {
        (next: AnyObject!) -> () in
            let nextAsT = next as! T
            nextClosure(nextAsT)
        }
    }

    func filterAs<T>(nextClosure:(T!) -> Bool) -> (RACSignal) {
            return self.filter {
                (next: AnyObject!) -> Bool in
                if(next == nil){
                    return nextClosure(nil)
                }else{
                    let nextAsT = next as! T
                    return nextClosure(nextAsT)
                }
            }
    }

    func mapAs<T>(nextClosure:(T!) -> AnyObject!) -> (RACSignal) {
            return self.map {
                (next: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! in
                if(next == nil){
                    return nextClosure(nil)
                }else{
                    let nextAsT = next as! T
                    return nextClosure(nextAsT)
                }
            }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though what you wrote seems to be correct, those Colin Eberhart's extensions were made a lot time ago for the RAC v2, when RAC v3 was in early development stage. Nowadays it's a Release Candidate version already, so why not use it instead? It's handy enough. Xcode will automatically detect `Signal`'s type

```
intSignal
    |> filter { num in num % 2 == 0 }
    |> map(toString)
    |> observe(next: { string in println(string) })
```

More info in [README.md](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) or [Documentation folder](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: wow sick!! is  "|>" syntactic sugar for all the lengthy code that used to be there before!? thank you so much for answering my questions. You seem to be a guru at ReactiveCocoa

Comment: Well, it's not a syntactic sugar, it's a whole new architecture. It's not `RACSignal` anymore, it's `Signal<T,ErrorType>`. `map` is not an instance method returning other signal anymore, it's a global function returning closure. `|>` is just an operator which wraps this closure around receiver. I'm just using the ReactiveCocoa :)

Comment: questino @ReDectection ugh The release candidate version is really annoying to integrate into my project. I followed their instructions and brought the .xcodeproject file into my folder using xcode and tried adding ReactiveCocoa.framework using "Embed binary" from General tab but it doesn't build .... did you do it manually like that?  It was a lot easier using Carthage but manually doing it is such a pain

Comment: I only used Carthage for ReactiveCocoa. Anyway, adding framework with Embed Binary is strange — there is "Link Binary With Libraries" for that, isn't it?